# How to access external samba server through the terminal in order to copy files from a different server via ssh

Tags: server, mount, ssh, samba, cifs

I have access to an external samba server through the GUI method outlined here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-connect.html.en

which has worked fine and I have access to all the files. However, I cannot access the files through the terminal. When I right click to find the location of the folder, it says the location is `smb://<university URL>/shared/`. However I cannot access this folder through the terminal.

I have tried at length to mount the server onto a local folder using `cifs` and I cannot get it to work - usually I get mount error (6). I have basically given up on accessing through this method and I think it might be a problem on the server end rather than on my end. However considering I can access the files through the gui method I am wondering if there is just some way of accessing through the terminal that does not explicitly involve mounting it onto a local folder.

The reason why I need to do this is simply to move some very large datafiles from an external supercomputer server via ssh to my university shared server and I have to do it through the terminal. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1

Edit: I have located the folder in the following location:

```
/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=<university URL>,share=shared
```

however, when I try to move files from the external supercomputer server to my university server using the following command:

```
scp -r <username>@<supercomputer URL>:<path to folder> /run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=<university URL>,share=shared/<path to desired folder>
```

it does not work and I get the following error:

```
/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=<university URL>,share=shared/<path to desired folder>/<folder>/<file1>: Invalid argument
```

and throws this error for every file in the folder. I have also tried using `rsync` rather than `scp` and this also does not work.

Comment: I have found the `mount` command options necessary vary with Ubuntu release (so user68186's question is spot on) as samba versions change and issues because of WannaCry and the like caused the changes.

Comment: Please feel free to answer your own question so that it may help others. Then you should accept your own answer.